# react-native-highcharts, can't access state variable inside event's load function and can access addPoints() outside the event's load function

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, highcharts, mobile-application

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-highcharts

chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function () {

```
                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.random();
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: Hi @Magudeshwaran, I recommend you to use the officially supported Highcharts wrapper: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native